# How to make a three-backgrounds centered page?

Tags: css, html, layout

I would like to build a web page that looks somewhat like this:
http://i62.tinypic.com/2rm8inm.png

I want to have backgrounds in three layers:

1. A background with repeat-x (red)
2. A background with repeat-y, centered and stretching the whole height, fixed width (blue)
3. A background that does not repeat, fixed height and width (green)

I have tried many different approaches, but they either do not scale correctly, or they will not fill the whole height.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: add your attempt/code in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a possible approach to the problem:

```
<div class="xrepeat">
     <div class="staticbg">
     </div>
</div>
```

And then give the body the background. Of course I picked random backgrounds where width and heights are messed up but you should get the idea:

Result:

http://jsfiddle.net/YTnv8/1/embedded/result/

Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/YTnv8/1/